# Check if string contains environment variable

Tags: c#, environment-variables

In .Net we have method `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` that allows us to replace all environment variables that provided string contains into its values.

But what if I only want to check if a string contains an environment variable?

Of course, I can compare the string before and after expanding, but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I think comparing is your best and only option.

Comment: Alternatively, you can get a list (actually, a dictionary) of key-value pairs using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables` and replace them yourself. But I am not sure if there are some corner cases which might be difficult to cover yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an extension that does a `Regex` search against the string

```
public static bool HasEnvironmentVariable(this string path)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"%[A-Za-z0-9\(\)]*%");
    Match match = regex.Match(path);

    return match.Success;
}
```